# SQL index based search

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing

I have a table called `Index` which has the columns `id` and `value`, where `id` is an auto-increment bigint and `value` is a varchar with an english word.

I have a table called `Search` which has relationships to the table `Index`. For each search you can define which indexes it should search in a table called `Article`.

The table `Article` also has relationships to the table `Index`.

The tables which define the relationships are:

`Searches_Indexes` with columns `id_search` and `id_index`.

`Articles_Indexes` with columns `id_article` and `id_index`.

I would like to find all Articles that contain the same indexes of Search.

For example: I have a `Search` with indexes `laptop` and `dell`, I would like to retrieve all `Article`s which contain both indexes, not just one.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT ai.id_article 
FROM articles_indexes AS ai 

INNER JOIN searches_indexes AS si 
ON si.id_index = ai.id_index 

WHERE si.id_search = 1
```

How do I make my SQL only return the `Article`s with all the `Index`es of a `Search`?

**Edit:**

**Sample Data:**

**Article:**

```
id | name          | description           | ...
1  | 'Dell Laptop' | 'New Dell Laptop...'  | ...
2  | 'HP Laptop'   | 'Unused HP Laptop...' | ...
...
```

**Search:**

```
id | name                 | id_user | ...
1  | 'Dell Laptop Search' | 5       | ...
```

**Index:**

```
id | value
1  | 'dell'
2  | 'laptop'
3  | 'hp'
4  | 'new'
5  | 'unused'
...
```

**Articles_Indexes:**

`Article` with `id` 1 (the dell laptop) has the `Index`es 'dell', 'laptop', 'new'.

`Article` with `id` 2 (the hp laptop) has the `Index`es 'laptop', 'hp', 'unused'.

```
id_article | id_index
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 4
...
2          | 2
2          | 3
2          | 5
...
```

**Searches_Indexes:**

`Search` with `id` 1 only contains 2 `Index`es, 'dell' and 'laptop':

```
id_search | id_index
1         | 1
1         | 2
```

**Required output:**

```
id_article
1
```

Comment: Tables called search and index... Which other tables to you have - column, where, select and value?

Comment: Updated to make it a bit more clear. I have two relationship tables `Searches_Indexes` and `Articles_Indexes`, which basically define which Searches have which Indexes, and which Articles have which Indexes.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've updated my question with sample data.

Comment: BTW [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation and a `HAVING` clause.  Assuming there are no duplicate entries in the indexes tables:

```
SELECT ai.id_article 
FROM articles_indexes ai INNER JOIN
     searches_indexes si 
     ON si.id_index = ai.id_index 
WHERE si.id_search = 1
GROUP BY ai.id_article
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM searches_indexes si2 WHERE si2.id_search = 1);
```

This counts the number of matches and makes sure it matches the number you are looking for.

I should add this.  If you wanted to look for all searches at the same time, I'd be inclined to write this as:

```
SELECT si.id_search, ai.id_article 
FROM articles_indexes ai INNER JOIN
     (SELECT si.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY si.id_index) as cnt
      FROM searches_indexes si 
     ) si
     ON si.id_index = ai.id_index 
GROUP BY si.id_search, ai.id_article, si.cnt
HAVING COUNT(*) = si.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare arrays. Here is some example:

```
create table article_index(id_article int, id_index int);
create table search_index(id_search int, id_index int);

insert into article_index
select generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,10);
insert into search_index
select generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,4);

select 
    id_article
from article_index
group by id_article
having array_agg(id_index) @> (select array_agg(id_index) from search_index where id_search = 2);
```

[Learn more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) about arrays in postgres.